# Infant crying causes (the) release of stress hormones in both infants and adults

Tags: definite-article

> Infant crying causes release of stress hormones in both infants and
>    adults.

or

> Infant crying causes **the** release of stress hormones in both infants and
>   adults.

I would use *the* because it is a countable noun and from what I know it should have some determiner.

Comment: To this US English speaker "Infant crying" sounds very strange.  I understand what you mean, but we don't usually modify a gerund (*crying*) with a noun (*infant*).  It would sound more natural to say "The crying of an infant".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/release):

> *release* [noun]
>
> [uncountable] the act of flowing out from somewhere:
>
> "The accident caused **the** release of radioactivity into the atmosphere."

Cambridge uses *the* here, so I would say the second form is more correct.

I (a native speaker) would also definitely go with the second form. It feels more correct, and the sentence is easier to read too. Or alternatively:

> Infant crying **causes stress hormones to be released** in both infants and adults.

— that's how I would phrase it if I wrote the sentence myself.